# Treating two arrays depending on one another without using loops, TypeError: only size-1 array can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

i'm new to python and i've been searching for a while though I didn't find any answer. The start of the code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


NTAB=np.array([25,40,60,100,160,250,400,600])

x,h=np.linspace(0,3,NTAB,retstep=True)
```

I need the value of x depending on NTAB. Obviously python is giving me the error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I don't want to use a loop to find the value. I tried many ways including defining original functions but it's still giving me the same error. What am I missing? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third argument of [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) is `num` which is the *number of samples* to be generated in the specified interval. This must be a positive integer.

So, try passing a *scalar* value instead:

```
In [43]: NTAB=np.array([25,40,60,100,160,250,400,600])

In [44]: x,h=np.linspace(0,3,NTAB[0],retstep=True)
```